# Should I upgrade my raspberry pi bootloader?

Tags: pi-4, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, bootloader

I was reading a guide on how to update some stuff on the pi, and i stumbled upon a section where its about upgrading the bootloader. It got me interested because never had i thought of doing it, and i never have done it.

Typically i would not do this as im afraid i would permanently brick my Pi 4 but at the same time the prompt showed me that my bootloader is out of date by about 3 years.

```
*** UPDATE AVAILABLE ***
BOOTLOADER: update available
   CURRENT: Thu  3 Sep 12:11:43 UTC 2020 (1599135103)
    LATEST: Wed 11 Jan 17:40:52 UTC 2023 (1673458852)
   RELEASE: default (/lib/firmware/raspberrypi/bootloader/default)
            Use raspi-config to change the release.

  VL805_FW: Dedicated VL805 EEPROM
     VL805: up to date
   CURRENT: 000138c0
    LATEST: 000138c0
```

It will be installed using the following commands :

```
sudo rpi-eeprom-update
sudo rpi-eeprom-update -a
sudo reboot
```

It may be of note that my `/etc/default/rpi-eeprom-update` is set to default. Not sure if its referring to a stable release of the eeprom

```
FIRMWARE_RELEASE_STATUS="default"
```

Should i do it? In the scenario that something goes wrong is it fixable? because i doubt the bootloader can be fixed by simply formatting a SD card to a fresh OS. From what i know the bootloader is not on the OS but on the pi itself.

Comment: Unless the new firmware fixes a bug you have then leave the update to the operating system.

Comment: [This article](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-bootloader/) may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

There might be insignificant improvements to updating the bootloader, but you should update either way. There is very little risk of it failing and if it does fail there is a way to undo it with you needing only a spare SD card.

Using the Raspberry Pi Imager :

Choose OS > Misc Utility Images > Bootloader (Pi 4 family) > SD Card Boot (depending on where you will boot).

Flash it to your spare sd card, put it in the pi, power it on, wait for the screen to flash and go Green to indicating it was successful, then put back your old SD card where you Pi OS is. done